# Windows Phone 8: Checkbox in Application Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a windows phone 8 project. This application includes news and i'm stucked with application bar issue.
I need to filter my news according to checked categories. These categories will be in my application bar.

The user will open the menu and will filter the news according to his/her interests.
But here is the problem, i couldn't put the checkboxes into that application bar.

Here is the what i've done;

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="ApplicationBarHaberler" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" ForegroundColor="SeaShell" BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_news.png" Text="Haberler"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Politics"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Economy"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Sport"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I need to put checkbox and tick something and must filter the news.
Anyone can help about it please ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The platform simply does not support this. You could change the `Text` of each line to 'show politics'/'hide politics' as appropriate, toggling the description to show what will happen when the user selects that item.

For example, the PDF Reader has an item on its `ApplicationBar` that changes from 'single page view' to 'continuous view' depending on which mode it is currently in.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest three options. If you have four or less filters you can add them to your application bar as buttons. You can then change the image and text of the button when it is clicked to indicate if the user will get those feeds.

Example 1

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="ApplicationBarHaberler" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" ForegroundColor="SeaShell" BackgroundColor="DarkGreen">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_NoPolitics.png" Text="Politics" Click="OnPoliticsClicked"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_NoEconomy.png" Text="Economy" Click="OnEconomyClicked"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Images/appbar_NoSport.png" Text="Sport" Click="OnSportClicked"/>
```

```
private const int SportsButtonIndex = 2;
private void OnSportClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.FilteringSports = !ViewModel.FilteringSports;
    if(ViewModel.FilteringSports)
    {
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[SportsButtonIndex] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IconUri = new Uri("Images/appbar_FilterSports", UriKind.Relative);
    }
    else
    {
        (ApplicationBar.Buttons[SportsButtonIndex] as ApplicationBarIconButton).IconUri = new Uri("Images/appbar_NoSports", UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

The second idea is what Mike Dimmick suggested and to change the text of your MenuItems to indicate if you are filtering. The click event would look similar to what is above.

The third (and my favorite) is to have a Filters page. You would have a "filter" icon button that when clicked would navigate to a FilterPage that has all of your filters. This also gives you the advantage of adding more filters later. When you navigate back to the page you would filter the feeds.

Exmaple 3

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if ((e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back) && ChangingFilter)
    {
        Filter();
        ChangingFilter = false;
    }
}

private void OnFilterButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    ChangingFilter = true;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FilterPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The FilterPage would list all of the filters with a CheckBox to indicate if the user wants to view them.

Comment: I think, third will be healthy for maintenance and for the future of the application.Thanks for the idea buddy.

Comment: By the way, on my filterpage.xaml, i will use checkboxes right ? But how will i understand which checkboxes checked or unchecked and i will filter my news feed ? Can you help me a little more please ?

Comment: That's up to you. I have a static Filters class that I access from the filters page and from the page to be filtered.